Create column display number of image in MySQL
I want to create a column numberofimage. In which each cell in the numberofimage column will display the number of images in the addimage column
format of each cell in addimage column like:
[{"file":"vstorage.com\/sohoa\/han01\/\/123.jpg","name":"123.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","size":239709},{"file":"storage.com\/sohoa\/han01\/\/456.jpg","name":"456.png","type":"image\/png","size":1030361}]

I would count the number of each cell like this, but wrong result:
 SELECT * FROM `surveytemplate1` 
WHERE addphoto LIKE '%.gif%' 
OR addphoto LIKE '"Type:"image\/jpeg"' 
OR addphoto LIKE '"Type":"image\/png"' 
OR addphoto LIKE '"Type":"image\/jpg"'

So in the example above there are 2 pictures because there are 2 words: "Type:"image\/jpeg" and "Type":"image\/png"
So what formula should I use to achieve my desired results?
MySQL is v5.5


which mysql version are you using mysql 8 has json_table for such things, but you you should think about saving your data normalized

"I would count the number of each cell like this, but wrong result:" - where in that statement is any counting supposed to happen? All you are doing there, is limit the selection of records.

MySQL 5.5 is effectively abandonware, and has been for some time now. It no longer even gets security updates. Time to move to 8.0.

@JoelCoehoorn 8.0? that's outdated now too - MySQL 9 is the current version as of Autumn 2024.

@Dai: but when googling for "mysql download", you still find https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ with no 9.x version available.....

Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?    Note: most of the JSON content is not shown...

For MySQL 5.5 we can use ExtractValue function for XML instead parsing strings.
With data



id
addphoto




1
[{"file":"vstorage.com/sohoa/han01//123.jpg","name":"123.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":239709},{"file":"storage.com/sohoa/han01//456.jpg","name":"456.png","type":"image/png","size":1030361}]




Convert string to valid XML
From

[{"file":"vstorage.com/sohoa/han01//123.jpg","name":"123.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":239709},{"file":"storage.com/sohoa/han01//456.jpg","name":"456.png","type":"image/png","size":1030361}]

To
<a>"file":"vstorage.com/sohoa/han01//123.jpg","name":"123.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":239709</a>,<a>"file":"storage.com/sohoa/han01//456.jpg","name":"456.png","type":"image/png","size":1030361</a>    

With request
select t.id
  ,replace(replace(substring(addphoto,2,length(addphoto)-2)
      ,'{','<a>'),'}','</a>') pxml
  ,addphoto
from surveytemplate1 t


Extract all image properties as string with ExtractValue

select id ,ExtractValue(replace(replace(substring(addphoto,2,length(addphoto)-2),'{','<a>'),'}','</a>'),'//a[1]') pxml 
from surveytemplate1

Output



id
pxml




1
"file":"vstorage.com/sohoa/han01//123.jpg","name":"123.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":239709


1
"file":"storage.com/sohoa/han01//456.jpg","name":"456.png","type":"image/png","size":1030361


1





Convert this string to XML

concat(replace(replace(replace(replace(pxml
      ,'"file":"','<file>'),'","name":"','</file><name>'),'","type":"','</name><type>'
      ),'","size":','</type><size>'
  ),'</size>')

From
"file":"vstorage.com/sohoa/han01//123.jpg","name":"123.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":239709

To
<file>vstorage.com/sohoa/han01//123.jpg</file><name>123.jpg</name><type>image/jpeg</type><size>239709</size>

Extract image attributes:
select id,count(imagename) cnt
from(
select id
  ,ExtractValue(pxml1,'//file') filepath
  ,ExtractValue(pxml1,'//name') imagename
  ,ExtractValue(pxml1,'//type') imagetype
  ,ExtractValue(pxml1,'//size') imagesize
from(
select id
  ,concat(replace(replace(replace(replace(pxml
      ,'"file":"','<file>'),'","name":"','</file><name>'),'","type":"','</name><type>'
      ),'","size":','</type><size>'
  ),'</size>') pxml1
from(
select id ,ExtractValue(replace(replace(substring(addphoto,2,length(addphoto)-2)
             ,'{','<a>'),'}','</a>'),'//a[1]') pxml 
from surveytemplate1
union all
select id ,ExtractValue(replace(replace(substring(addphoto,2,length(addphoto)-2)
               ,'{','<a>'),'}','</a>'),'//a[2]') pxml 
from surveytemplate1
union all
select id ,ExtractValue(replace(replace(substring(addphoto,2,length(addphoto)-2)
               ,'{','<a>'),'}','</a>'),'//a[3]') pxml 
from surveytemplate1
)a
)b
)c
WHERE imagetype in('image\/jpeg','image\/png','image\/jpg')
group by id




id
cnt




1
2



For clearity, before group by we have
select id
  ,ExtractValue(pxml1,'//file') filepath
  ,ExtractValue(pxml1,'//name') imagename
  ,ExtractValue(pxml1,'//type') imagetype
  ,ExtractValue(pxml1,'//size') imagesize
from(
select id
  ,concat(replace(replace(replace(replace(pxml
      ,'"file":"','<file>'),'","name":"','</file><name>'),'","type":"','</name><type>'
      ),'","size":','</type><size>'
  ),'</size>') pxml1
from(
select id ,ExtractValue(replace(replace(substring(addphoto,2,length(addphoto)-2),'{','<a>'),'}','</a>'),'//a[1]') pxml 
from surveytemplate1
union all
select id ,ExtractValue(replace(replace(substring(addphoto,2,length(addphoto)-2),'{','<a>'),'}','</a>'),'//a[2]') pxml 
from surveytemplate1
union all
select id ,ExtractValue(replace(replace(substring(addphoto,2,length(addphoto)-2),'{','<a>'),'}','</a>'),'//a[3]') pxml 
from surveytemplate1
)a
)b





id
filepath
imagename
imagetype
imagesize




1
vstorage.com/sohoa/han01//123.jpg
123.jpg
image/jpeg
239709


1
storage.com/sohoa/han01//456.jpg
456.png
image/png
1030361


1
null
null
null
null



fiddle

A possible solution:
select count(*)
from
json_table(
  '[{"file":"vstorage.com\/sohoa\/han01\/\/123.jpg","name":"123.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","size":239709},{"file":"storage.com\/sohoa\/han01\/\/456.jpg","name":"456.png","type":"image\/png","size":1030361}]',
  '$[*]' COLUMNS( file varchar(64) PATH '$.file' ERROR ON ERROR )
) as jt

Explanation:

json_table converts your JSON into a relation called jt
from which selecting `count(*) yields your result
the input is your JSON
the second parameter of json_table specifies the columns, here I was only interested of file

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/

To count images you can use json_length(addphoto).
Or expand json by JSON_TABLE and count rows.
See example:
Test source:
create table surveytemplate1 (id int, addphoto varchar(1000));
insert into surveytemplate1 values
 (1,'[{"file":"vstorage.com\/sohoa\/han01\/\/123.jpg","name":"123.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","size":239709},{"file":"storage.com\/sohoa\/han01\/\/456.jpg","name":"456.png","type":"image\/png","size":1030361}]')
;




id
addphoto




1
[{"file":"vstorage.com/sohoa/han01//123.jpg","name":"123.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":239709},{"file":"storage.com/sohoa/han01//456.jpg","name":"456.png","type":"image/png","size":1030361}]



Simple query
select t.id,json_length(addphoto) cnt
  ,addphoto
from surveytemplate1 t
WHERE addphoto LIKE '%.gif%' 
OR addphoto LIKE '"Type:"image\/jpeg"' 
OR addphoto LIKE '"Type":"image\/png"' 
OR addphoto LIKE '"Type":"image\/jpg"'
;

Output



id
cnt
addphoto




1
2
[{"file":"vstorage.com/sohoa/han01//123.jpg","name":"123.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":239709},{"file":"storage.com/sohoa/han01//456.jpg","name":"456.png","type":"image/png","size":1030361}]



Example with JSON_TABLE
select t.id,jv.*
  ,json_length(addphoto) cnt
from surveytemplate1 t
cross join json_table(addphoto
  , "$[*]" 
      COLUMNS(
          idx FOR ORDINALITY
        ,filepath VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.file"
        ,imagename VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.name"
        ,imagetype VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.type"
        ,imagesize VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.size"
      ) 
 ) jv
;




id
idx
filepath
imagename
imagetype
imagesize
cnt




1
1
vstorage.com/sohoa/han01//123.jpg
123.jpg
image/jpeg
239709
2


1
2
storage.com/sohoa/han01//456.jpg
456.png
image/png
1030361
2



If you whant count only images of selected types
select id,count(*) as numberofuploadimage
from(
select t.id,jv.*
  ,json_length(addphoto) cnt
from surveytemplate1 t
cross join json_table(addphoto
  , "$[*]" 
      COLUMNS(
          idx FOR ORDINALITY
        ,filepath VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.file"
        ,imagename VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.name"
        ,imagetype VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.type"
        ,imagesize VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.size"
      ) 
 ) jv
)t
WHERE imagetype in('image\/jpeg','image\/png','image\/jpg')
group by id

You can extract only image type from json (imagetype VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.type").
fiddle
Update1.
It may be useful to check the validity of the string for the JSON format before converting using JSON_TABLE.
I have added a few rows to the example that may occur in your data.
select s.id,counts.numberofuploadimage,s.addphoto
from surveytemplate1 s
left join(
  select id,count(*) as numberofuploadimage
  from(
    select t.id,jv.*
     ,json_length(addphoto) cnt
    from surveytemplate1 t
    cross join json_table(addphoto
     , "$[*]" 
        COLUMNS(
            idx FOR ORDINALITY
          ,filepath VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.file"
          ,imagename VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.name"
          ,imagetype VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.type"
          ,imagesize VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.size"
        ) 
     ) jv
    where json_valid(addphoto)
  ) as t
  WHERE imagetype in('image\/jpeg','image\/png','image\/jpg')
  group by id
) as counts on counts.id=s.id




id
numberofuploadimage
addphoto




1
2
[{"file":"vstorage.com/sohoa/han01//123.jpg","name":"123.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":239709},{"file":"storage.com/sohoa/han01//456.jpg","name":"456.png","type":"image/png","size":1030361}]


2
1
[{"file":"vstorage.com/sohoa/han02//123.jpg","name":"123(2).jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":239709},{"file":"storage.com/sohoa/han03//456.jpg","name":"456(2).png","size":1030361}]


3
1
[{"file":"vstorage.com/sohoa/han02//123.jpg","name":"123(2).jpg","type":"image/jpeg","size":239709}]


4
null
[{}]


5
null
[]


6
null



7
null
null



fiddle

thank you for your guide. i've used 'select Feedbacknumber,count() as numberofuploadimage
from(
select t.Feedbacknumber,jv.
,json_length(addphoto) cnt
from surveytemplate1 t
cross join json_table(addphoto
, "$[*]"
COLUMNS(
idx FOR ORDINALITY
,filepath VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.file"
,imagename VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.name"
,imagetype VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.type"
,imagesize VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.size"
)
) jv
)t
WHERE imagetype in('image/jpeg','image/png','image/jpg')
group by Feedbacknumber' but error (MySQL 5.5).

Screenshot hier: https://i.imgur.com/KZrj9da.png thanks

Yeah, it was surprising - MySQL 5.5

thank you. I update to MySQL v8 and see error 'Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_table: "The document is empty." at position 0.' imgur.com/RQSuuJp How can i fix it? Thank you

I have added an example with checking the correctness of JSON. Show on which data the error you specified occurs.

Hier is my column screenshot. https://imgur.com/OwiStEE . Maybe some cell in 'addimage' column don't have data ? Thanks
